# Correct way to execute multiple reactive operations

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflow, project-reactor

I get from a reactive repository a `Mono<FooBar>` based on it's value I have to create two other objects save them using reactive repositories, modify `FooBar` object and save it as well.

As I'm new to reactive programming I landed with the following solution, which is working, but I'm not sure if I'm using correctly the reactive API:

```
@Test
void createAndSave() {
    Mono<FooBar> fooBarMono = findFooBar()  // returns Mono<FooBar>
            .map(fooBar -> {
        createAndSaveLoremBar(fooBar).subscribe();   // returns Mono<LoremBar>
        createAndSaveDoloremBar(fooBar).subscribe(); // returns Mono<DoloremBar>

        fooBar.setActive(true);

        return saveFooBar(fooBar);          // returns Mono<FooBar>
    }).flatMap(Function.identity());

    StepVerifier.create(fooBarMono)
            .expectNextMatches(Objects::nonNull)
            .expectComplete()
            .verify();

}
```

from console log:

```
   saved lorem bar
   saved dolorem bar
   saved foo bar
```

Comment: Is it required to save lorem bar and dolorem bar before activating fooBar? And what about errors on lorem and dolorem saving? Should we ignore or propagate errors?

Comment: @AlexanderPankin the order of saving doesn't matter; errors should be propagated if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, mutating objects in the asynchronous (reactive) world is not a good idea.

Anyway, in your solution possible errors on lorem and dolorem saving are ignored. You can improve it like so:

```
Mono<FooBar> fooBarMono = findFooBar()
        .flatMap(fooBar -> Flux.merge(
                createAndSaveLoremBar(fooBar),
                createAndSaveDoloremBar(fooBar)) // asynchronously saving lorem and dolorem
                .then(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {  // if there wasn't errors, mutate and save fooBar
                    fooBar.setActive(true);
                    return fooBar;
                }).flatMap(fooBar1 -> saveFooBar(fooBar1))));
```

If you could create copy of your `fooBar` with true `active` flag, the code could be simpler. For example with lombok.

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class FooBar {
...
}

Mono<FooBar> fooBarMono = findFooBar()
        .flatMap(fooBar -> Flux.merge(
                createAndSaveLoremBar(fooBar),
                createAndSaveDoloremBar(fooBar))
                .then(saveFooBar(fooBar.toBuilder().active(true).build())));
```

And if you are not interested in the result of your `saveFooBar(...)` but only in the completion signal, you could make all three saves asynchronously:

```
Flux<Object> flux = findFooBar()
        .flatMapMany(fooBar -> Flux.merge(
                createAndSaveLoremBar(fooBar),
                createAndSaveDoloremBar(fooBar),
                saveFooBar(fooBar.toBuilder().active(true).build())));
```

Actually, in the last approach you could collect all three results and you should prefer this approach, but I don't have enough information about your classes and requirements for creating full example.

Answer (score 7):

I think the bellow solution is a little bit more readable. Anyway Alexander is correct you should never ever modify the input. You see we are borrowing a lot of concept form functional programming. For example you call `Function.identity()` this is called 
`identity functor`. Both `Flux`and `Mono` are monads. And there is a concept that is secret for these guys called `Referential transparency` that imperative update break.

```
    final Mono<FooBar> fooBarMono1 = findFooBar()
            .zipWhen((fooBar) -> createAndSaveLoremBar(fooBar))
            .map(tuple -> tuple.getT1())
            .zipWhen((fooBar) -> createAndSaveDoloremBar(fooBar))
            .map(tuple -> tuple.getT1())
            .map(fooBar -> new FooBar(true))
            .flatMap(fooBar -> saveFooBar(fooBar));
```

Or more concise:

```
    final Mono<FooBar> fooBarMono1 = findFooBar()
            .zipWhen((fooBar) -> createAndSaveLoremBar(fooBar)
                                    .then(createAndSaveDoloremBar(fooBar)))
            .map(tuple -> tuple.getT1())
            .map(fooBar -> new FooBar(true))
            .flatMap(fooBar -> saveFooBar(fooBar));
```